# Change the position of button and text relative to table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having table and I have on top of it in the right side button 
and in the left side some text.(they parallel)
Currently its very close to the table which is below and I want to move
the text and the button little bit up ,how should I do that ?

```
<h4 style="display:inline">Users Table</h4>
<div style="float:right" class="text-right">

    <a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;New</a>

</div>

//Here start the table

@* List of users *@
<table class="table table-striped  ">
```

If I use the `<br />` it move it lot up ,there is a way to do it by pixels?

Comment: Since you are using a float, the element (table) under it should be cleared to be able and make use of a margin :) see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a div surrounding the text and the button and apply some margin-bottom to that.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    <h4 style="display:inline">Users Table</h4>
    <div style="float:right" class="text-right">

        <a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;New</a>

    </div>
</div>

//Here start the table

@* List of users *@
<table class="table table-striped  ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're useing Bootstrap you can do a simple [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to accomplish that.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <h4>Users Table</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- table -->
```

I don't know what `.text-right` does, but probably can be applyed to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using CSS you can add padding like this :

```
          style="padding-top:0.5px;"
```

Or

```
           style="padding-bottom:0.5px;"
```

Comment: Thanks black hole,I have already the "display:inline"> in the style can I add also the padding to it?if yes how?

Comment: Your welcome .yes you can,just separate the commands by semicolon like this :
style="display:inline;padding-top:0.5px;"

Comment: I try it and nothing happen ,any idea why?

Comment: I don't think padding would work well on an inline element.. btw typo in 'padding-bot' should be 'bottom'

Comment: @webkit I play Dota2 so i always say bot instead of bottom :D

Comment: lol well maybe you should write a Dota2er's script that will scrape your css and replace all bot with bottom ;]

Answer (score 0):

do this in your css:

```
table.table { clear:both; margin-top:10px;}
```